# Can't see the bottom of the installation window

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, display-resolution, asus, window

Hi I have a Asus Rog Strix GL703VD and when I try to install ubuntu first I have to either chose "safe display" or set the settings to 'nouveau.modeset=0' (it boots showing command lines but then it gets stuck...) Otherwise it doesn't boot it just cut while loading. But when I chose to either install first or boot into ubuntu then install, I cannot see the bottom of the install window, I cannot resize it (resolution is stuck tot 600/900 4:3)and I can't seem to change the font to see the whole window and I cannot go to the bottom of it.

Thank you in advance for any welcoming help!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem is limited to the last version of Ubuntu 20.04
Tried out with ubuntu 18.04.4 and seems to work fine, I'm about to install it.
Though still have to use nouveau.modeset=0 but planning to upgrade it as soon as the install is done. Or while the install.
Thank you anyways! And hoping to still get some insight from someone who knows what is the issue with the 20.04 version.